# Flight PHP REST service always returns "Hello World"

Tags: php, rest, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2, url-rewrite-module

I am trying to build a REST data service with [Flight](http://flightphp.com/) as it seems to be easy to understand but even so I cannot get the simple out-of-the-box demo working. I am running on a Windows 2008 R2 with IIS 7.5, URL Rewrite and PHP 5.4 on top.

I have imported this `.htaccess` file in to the IIS URL Rewrite module:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

IIS imports it without any problems:

[image: IIS imports it without any problems]

I then have this PHP code:

```
<?PHP
require 'flight/Flight.php';

Flight::route("/", function (){
    echo 'Hello World';
});

Flight::route('/blog(/@year(/@month(/@day)))', function($year, $month, $day){
    // This will match the following URLS:
    // /blog/2012/12/10
    // /blog/2012/12
    // /blog/2012
    // /blog
    echo "Blog year=[$year], month=[$month], day=[$day]<br />";
});

Flight::start();
?>
```

If I request `http://myserver/blog/2012` or `http://myserver/what/ever` I always get the front page text, "Hello World".

For me it looks like the URL rewriting is working as I at least don't get a 404-error but what am I missing?

Comment: Is there really no comments to this? I really would like for this to work and I cannot see why this doesn't work. Is it the URL rewriting that fails or am I doing something wrong in the PHP code?

Comment: The routes are matched in order of declaration, since / matches first it is always selected. Just change the order of the route directives.

Answer (score 0):

If you add return true in a route it goes to the next one.

```
Flight::route("/what", function (){
    echo 'Hello World';
    return true;
});
```

This will go to /what/ever